# Loading multiple files from Google Cloud Storage into a single Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I have been trying to write a function that loads multiple files from a Google Cloud Storage bucket into a single Pandas Dataframe, however I cannot seem to make it work.

```
import pandas as pd
from google.datalab import storage
from io import BytesIO


def gcs_loader(bucket_name, prefix):
  bucket = storage.Bucket(bucket_name)
  df = pd.DataFrame()
  for shard in bucket.objects(prefix=prefix):
    fp = shard.uri
    %gcs read -o $fp -v tmp
    df.append(read_csv(BytesIO(tmp))
  return df
```

When I try to run it says:

> undefined variable referenced in command line: $fp

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The interesting thing is that when the code is not run inside a function, the magic works fine. My conclusion is that it must be a restriction of placing the magic commands inside functions, but I haven't been able to find information about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, here's an example:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=0B7I8C_4vGdF6Ynl1X25iTHE4MGc

This notebook shows the following:

1. Create two random CSVs
2. Upload both CSV files to a GCS bucket
3. Uses the GCS Python API to iterate over files in the bucket. And,
4. Merge each file into a single Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Still working for me. What error did you encounter?

Comment: I forgot what error I was getting, but it is working properly now. Thanks.