# pd.read_json() to read all json files in a folder

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have 100 large json files in gcs and want to load them in a panda dataframe. I've used something like below in dask:

```
 dd.read_json('gs://dask_poc/2018-04-18/data-*.json')
```

But when I used:

```
 pd.read_json('gs://dask_poc/2018-04-18/data-*.json')
```

I got the below error:
     ValueError: Expected object or value

Wondering if panda cant aggregate all the files together similar to dask?

Comment: This may sound like a silly question and I probably already know the answer, but where are you running this code?

Comment: @coldspeed locally in my jupyterlab

Comment: you could probably use a for loop to open each file in that folder rand execute whatever code you have for each json file

Comment: Unfortunately, pandas does not have native GCP support, nor can it be expected to magically understand GCP links.

Comment: Does the answer to this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885631/loading-multiple-files-from-google-cloud-storage-into-a-single-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @coldspeed I thought the same but today when I check this link, they put gcs as a path too! https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Comment: Well, I'm floored. How is that possible without any authentication from your part?

Comment: @saul cruz yeah, saw similar answers but my files are huge and concat may not be promising nor for loop.

Comment: @coldspeed lol, not sure

Comment: Learned about gcs support in pandas today, thanks guys!
See [`pandas.io.gsc.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/io/gcs.py), and [`gcsfs` documentation](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for some details.
Not sure what the described error is.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52106361/6914989) could help. Looks like glob aggregation has to be done manually for pandas.